# "I'm done" Review button doesn't fade out when unclickable

Tags: bug, status-completed

To be able to click the "I'm done" button on the firsts posts queue, you need to first *do* something.  However, the button appears the same when I've done nothing (and it should be faded out).

[image: Like this]

As you can see, the button shows as clickable but isn't. When I've upvoted the post and go to click the button, it looks the same (but gains a hover effect).

Running Firefox Quantum here on OS X El Capitan.

Comment: Replicated on both mobile phone and Firefox quantum (ha!) On a  laptop running Windows 10 [no, I still haven't gotten round to installing Linux]

Comment: I've noticed that the "no action needed" button doesn't fade out when I've done something (on an acer chromebook).

Comment: @heather huh, I forgot it even did that.  But yeah, repro'ed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is now fixed as per the images below, at least on the latest version of Firefox on a laptop running Windows 10.

[image]

[image]

Under the assumption that this is fixed for all browsers etc. I'll mark this as complete, although if it's still not working for anyone, leave a comment below here and I can undo that.